# Footer slides from bottom up, click does not stay active

Tags: html, css, onclick, css-selectors, css-transforms

I'm trying to make a full width clickable bar on the fixed bottom page when on click the box would slide from the bottom (previously hidden) up.

I have made the sliding and the bar but when I click on the bar I have to press and hold the button to stay up how do I make it on click to stay active and then click anywhere out ow that bar and box it would go back down.

If at all possible to do with pure CSS.

```css
#slideout p {
  text-align:center;
}
#slideout {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  width:100%;
  background:#555;
  height:60px;
}
#slideout_inner {
  bottom:-100px;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
}
#slideout:active{
  bottom: 300px;
}

#slideout:active #slideout_inner {
  bottom: 150px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideout">
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <div id="slideout_inner">
    [form code goes here]
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure CSS, you *can* do it using radio button/checkbox and their corresponding layout to work like a `click`.

1. Use a hidden checkbox and `#slideout` as its label.
2. Replace your `active` style to these:

   ```
   input[type=checkbox] {
     display: none;
   }
   input[type=checkbox]:checked + label#slideout {
     bottom: 300px;
   }
   input[type=checkbox]:checked + label div#slideout_inner {
     bottom: 150px;
     position: fixed;
   }
   ```

See example below:

```css
#slideout p {
  text-align: center;
}
#slideout {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  background: #555;
  height: 60px;
}
#slideout_inner {
  bottom: -100px;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
/*
#slideout:active{
  bottom: 300px;
}

#slideout:active #slideout_inner {
  bottom: 150px;
    position:fixed;
}
*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label#slideout {
  bottom: 300px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label div#slideout_inner {
  bottom: 150px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="slideout_checkbox" />
<label id="slideout" for="slideout_checkbox">
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <div id="slideout_inner">
    [form code goes here]
  </div>
</label>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you exactly what i was looking for. Is it possible by any chance that the box would close even if u click outside of the bar like anywhere up top?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is easily done using jQuery and using an 'active' class.

For instance:

```
$('.toggler').on('click', function() {
  if($('footer').hasClass('active')) {
    $('footer').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('footer').addClass('active');
  }
}
```

As for the 'click anywhere to close' you could use:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest('footer').length) {
    if ($('footer').hasClass('active')) {
      $('footer').removeClass('active');
    };
  }
});
```

I think the first one is pretty self-explantory. As for the second one, you basically capture the click event (e) and if the event happens anywhere but the footer, remove the active class.

Source: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Thank you but it needs to be pure css